# getting error to send mail in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0, sendmail

Hi i am trying to send mail in `cakephp` but getting below **error message**:

> stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
>   Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
>   stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
>   stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:25
>   (Unknown error)

And here is my `controller` code:-

```
public function contact(){
    //$this->loadModel('Contact');
    if($this->request->is(array('put','post'))){
        $this->set('data', $this->request->data);
        $this->Email->from = $this->data['Page']['email'];
        $this->Email->to = 'staff@mailinator.com';
        $this->Email->subject = 'Contact';
        $this->Email->template = 'contact';
        $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
        $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
        'post'=>465,
        'host'=>'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'username'=>'staff@gmail.com',
        'password'=>'123456',
        'client'=>'gmail.com');
        $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
        //$this->Email->send();
        if($this->Email->send()) {
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'index'));
        }
        else{
            CakeLog::write('debug', $this->Email->smtpError);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

there should be 'port'=>465 not 'post'=>465 . please correct